# Tailwind: Incorrect center positioning: w-1/2 doesn't work flex justify-center becomes left-aligned [fiddle]

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Fiddle: https://play.tailwindcss.com/J4squDRAp7

My code:

```html
<div class="bg-gray-500">
     <div class="w-1/2 flex justify-center">
        <textarea/>
   </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this (not sure why the div text is inside textarea):

[image]

I want it to look like this (be centered):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `flex justify-center` into the parent class

```
 <div class="bg-gray-500 flex justify-center">
     <div class="w-1/2 text-center">
        <textarea/>
     </div>
 </div>
```

working [DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mkZPi5UtBb)